# Integration by Residue

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I evaluate $$\int_{C(0,e)} \frac{1-\cos z}{(e^z-1)\sin z}dz.$$
This looks simple but I have a hard time to find the residue at $z=0$.

At $z=0$ the function say $f(z)$ is even undefined. I guess I am missing some key idea.

Comment: What is $C(0,e)$? I know it's probably some circle in $\mathbb{C}$ but I'm unfamiliar with that notation ...

Comment: The singularity at $z=0$ is removable. The integrand limits to $\frac12$ at $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

for $n \in \mathbb{Z} $ if you integrate $az^n$ round a circle centered at the origin the result is zero except in the case $n=-1$, in which case it computes to $2\pi ia$. $a$ is called the residue.

in a neighbourhood of the origin your integrand actually has no singularity at $0$ (called a "removable singularity") because it can be expressed as a Maclaurin series around the origin:
$$
\frac{1-\cos z}{(e^z-1)\sin z} = \frac{\frac{z^2}2 - o(z^3)}{(z+o(z))(z+o(z^3))} \\
=\frac{\frac12-o(z^5)}{(1+o(z^2)(1+o(z^2))} \\
=\frac12+o(z^2)
$$
hence the integral is zero.

Comment: See my comment to the question: $1-\cos(z)=\frac12z^2+O(z^4)$

Comment: $$\frac{\frac12z^2+O(z^4)}{(z+O(z^2))(z+O(z^3))}=\frac{\frac12+O(z^2)}{(1+O(z))(1+O(z^2))}=\frac12+O(z)$$ This doesn't affect the end result, but it is nice not to confuse the reader.

Comment: thx. just noticed my mistake

Comment: I did not get $ 1-\cos z=z^2/2 + \mathbb{O}(z^4)$

Comment: it follows from the expansion $\cos z = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} \cdots$ and the definition of the Landau $O$ notation for terms which become small

Comment: Hi David Holden: How did you get rid of the bottom? I think this Landau $0$ has to do with the absolute value. $0(z^2)$ means: $f(z)=a_2 z^2+a_3 z^3+..........$ such that  $|f(z)|\leq A |z^2|$ for some constant $A$. This is what I understood. How did you apply this idea with out using any inequality?

Comment: using the binomial expansion $(1+a)^{-1}=1+a+O(a^2)$.

Comment: btw my expression used "little o" which is the wrong choice. sorry for that. i was thinking of limits as $z \to \infty$ look at @robjohn's comment just above for the correct form. i will endeavour to adjust my answer in due course